# Test whether data is numeric or Factor/Ordinal

Tags: r, types

I'm sitting with a large dataset and want to get som basic information about my variables, first of all if they are numeric or factor/ordinal.

I'm working with a function, and want, one variable at a time, investigate if it is numeric or a factor.

To make the for loop work I'm using dataset[i] to get to the variable I want.

```
object<-function(dataset){

    n=ncol(dataset)
    for(i in 1:n){
       variable_name<-names(dataset[i])
       factor<-is.factor(dataset[i])
       rdered<-is.ordered(dataset[i])
       numeric<-is.numeric(dataset[i])
       print(list(variable_name,factor,ordered,numeric))
    }
}
```

is.ordered
My problem is that is.numeric() does not seem to work with dataset[i], all the results becomes "FALSE", but only with dataset$.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What is the type of `dataset`? `data.frame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str(dataset)` to get summary information on an object, but to solve your problem you need to compeletely extract your data with double square brackets. Single square bracket subsetting keeps the output as a sub-list (or data.frame) rather than extracting the contents:

```
str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
is.numeric(iris[1])
[1] FALSE
class(iris[1])
[1] "data.frame"
is.numeric(iris[[1]])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @user20650 You are right, I'll remove that remark. They are numbers (integers) under the hood, but `is.numeric` doesn't pick up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dataset` is something like a `data.frame`, you can do the following (and avoid the loop):

```
names = sapply(dataset, names) # or simply `colnames(dataset)`
types = sapply(dataset, class)
```

Then `types` gives you either `numeric` or `factor`. You can then simply do something like this:

```
is_factor = types == 'factor'
```